# Find a symmetric matrix B that makes ABC symmetric, A,C known

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two known matricies $\bf{A} \in \mathbb{R}_{nxm} $,  $\bf{C} \in \mathbb{R}_{mxn}$ with $m>n$.

I'm trying to find a $\bf{B} \in \mathbb{R}_{mxm}$ that is symmetric and makes $\bf{ABC}$ Symmetric.
$\bf{B}\neq0$

Right so,

$\bf{B'}=\bf{B}$

$\bf{ABC} = \bf{C'B'A'} = \bf{C'BA'}$

*Edit:*
From user1551, we can define a $\bf{S}$ which is symmetric:

$\bf{B} = A^{+}SC^{+}$ + any combination of vectors from the null space of $\bf{A}$

The question then becomes how to we symmeterize $\bf{B}$ by adding the null space vectors?

Comment: A trivial example comes to mind...

Comment: Without further requirement, you can take $B$ to be the zero matrix; that's probably what Git Gud is talking about.

Comment: Ah, then yes, make sure $B\neq0$

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is less than $n$, let $v$ be any nonzero vector in the nullspace of $A$ and let every column of $B$ be $v$. Then $ABC=0$ is a symmetric matrix. Similarly when $C$ has deficient rank. If both $A$ and $C$ are full-rank, take $B=A^+SC^+$ for any $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $S$, where $A^+$ and $C^+$ are the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverses of $A$ and $C$ respectively. Then $ABC=S$.

Comment: That is really helpful, but is it possible to solve for a symmetric B given the case A,C are rank=n.  I tried to recursively solve for that condition but I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: Your last comment and the question update are quite different. Of course it is because "A and C of full rank means that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(C)=n$. Also, if they have both full rank and $B_0=A^+SC^+$, then other solutions can be written as $B=B_0+X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric such that $AX=0$ and $C'Y=0$, that is, $X$ and $Y$ are given by an outer product of matrices with their columns in the nullspace of $A$ and $C'$, respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked your requirement that $B$ is also symmetric, but I hope that my comment can still be of some help.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel my comment was in regards to user1551s comment, he mentioned that it would be rank dependent and I was just trying to be clear that they were of full rank.  In regards to your solution, X and Y being symmetric doesn't really improve the situation,  since $B_0$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Since this is still a system of linear equations, if you only need to solve it numerically, just throw the reformulated equation $\pmatrix{C^T\otimes A - (A\otimes C^T)K^{(m,m)}\\ I_{m^2}-K^{(m,m)}}\operatorname{vec}(B)=0$ at some numerical solver like Matlab. Here the symbol "$\otimes$" denotes a Kronecker product, $\operatorname{vec}(\cdot)$ denotes vectorisation and $K^{(m,n)}$ denotes a commutation matrix. See Wikipedia for brief explanations of these terms.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks!, I think I have a more general solution now, I need to work it out fully and I'll post a full update!  Thanks for the help I couldn't have finished without your input.

Comment: @user1551 Where can I learn about the reformulation you did? It seems to make solutions where S = 0, however I would like a non-zero result there (I know I didn't specify it, but it is ideal)

Comment: @Dar It's a usual system of linear equations, just a bit larger in scale. It has a nontrivial solution if and only if the matrix on the left of $\operatorname{vec}(B)$ has deficient column rank. The reformulation is obtained directly from the well-known fact that $\operatorname{vec}(ABC)=(C^T\otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)$ for any (square or rectangular) matrices $A,B,C$ whenever the product $ABC$ makes sense.